# How to work on same github repo from two systems?

Tags: git, github, dropbox

I work on multiple systems throughout the day. I've been trying to figure out a strategy to sharing my current working directory between the two systems.

The code is hosted on Github as a private repo. I was thinking of using a bare repo in dropbox like this:

```
    Github
       |
   Dropbox(bare repo)
     /      \
  Desktop   Laptop
```

I'm trying to avoid having tons of bogus checkins in my repo just so that the code is shared between the two systems. I tested this out, and it seemed to work to share code, but I'm thinking all the checkins will still pile up in the git log when i have to inevitably push from dropbox to github.

So my questions:

1. Would there be a way to edit the commits (im thinking something like squashing a bunch of commits into one) before pushing from the dropbox bare repo to github?
2. Should I be just putting the working directory into Dropbox (clone from github) and then using the code from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question on programmers from earlier today.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156309/working-with-git-on-multiple-machines) You might check out the answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip Dropbox entirely. Instead, use topic branches for work in progress, then `rebase` or otherwise improve your history when you're ready to merge to `master`.

The workflow would look something like this:

1. Get the urge to code a feature. Make it a topic branch: `git checkout -B <topic> master`
2. Code away on `<topic>`. Commit as often as you'd like, in whatever state you'd like.
3. At the end of the day / session, push to github: `git push origin <topic>`
4. When hopping to the other machine, checkout `<topic>` and track it: `git checkout --track origin/<topic>` or `git pull origin <topic>` if you already have it checked out.
5. Repeat steps 2-3 until that topic is done.

When you're ready to merge with `master` or `production`, use `git rebase -i` to give `<topic>` a logical, debuggable, maintainable history.

Comment: Do you delete these topic branches when finished?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not terribly disciplined about it. I usually go 3-4 cycles before getting annoyed enough at `git branch -a`'s output to do something about it, at which point I clean the merged ones up. It's a matter of personal taste. There are no performance consequences to having a few dozen branches lying around.