# One developer, two laptops, git, github, and dropbox - how to?

Tags: git, github, dropbox

**EDIT: I REALIZE THAT THIS SCENARIO UNNECESSARILY INCLUDES DROPBOX. YOU CAN JUST PUSH/PULL FROM/TO GITHUB ON EACH MACHINE.**

---

1. I want to keep my projects in dropbox so it's easy to share the contents with multiple computers, in my case, two laptops (one home, one work).
2. I want to use GIT for version control.
3. I want to store each project's repo in Github.

**Currently:** I have my personal laptop already set up with git & github. I've already pushed to github, etc.

What I'm looking to do is add my work laptop into the equation. How is this done? ***I need step-by-step instructions***. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424647/how-to-work-on-same-github-repo-from-two-systems) that a similar setup is being done with setting up a "bare repo" in dropbox. I've googled but still am unclear as to how this is set up and how it works. Please help.

Comment: If you use github you don't need dropbox.

Comment: If you make sure you fetch/merge from your central Git repo (GitHub in this case) before you start your dev work, and then push when you are done, that would keep your remote repo up to date.  No matter which laptop you're on, starting dev (fetch/merge) and finishing dev (push) will keep everything up to date and in sync.  No need for dropbox.

Comment: Agreed @bmargulies... I realize now that Dropbox isn't necessary in this scenario. Total brain fart here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need dropbox to accomplish what you're saying here.

1. go to personal laptop and push all changes to github
2. go to work laptop and pull the project down using git
3. start working /committing / pushing changes
4. Read up on git and how it's used, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started

Comment: You know, just after I posted the question, I realized that in this scenario Dropbox is just an unnecessary middle man! I was getting all bent out of shape for nothing. Thanks @r00k.